# merge sort algorithm c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

Implementing a merge sort algorithm and When I run my code, the program crashes. I have tried debugging and & just seems to crash as soon as the call to the merge algorithm in the mergeSort algorithm is called. Any help & criticism of my code would be appreciated .

```
void merge(int* array, int first, int last) {
    int size = (last - first) + 1;
    int *array2 = new int[];

    int i = first;
    int mid = (first + last) / 2;
    int k = 0;
    int j = mid + 1;

    while (k < size) {
        if ((i <= mid) && (array[i] < array[j])) {
            array2[k++] = array[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            array2[k++] = array[j++];
        }
    }
    for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        array[first + k] = array2[k];
    }

    delete array2;
}

void mergeSort(int *array, int first, int last) {
    int mid;
    if (first < last) {
        mid = (first + last) / 2; //divide in half
        mergeSort(array,first, mid); //first recursive call
        mergeSort(array,mid + 1, last); //second recursive call
        merge(array,first, last);// call merge functon
    }
}
```

Main Function:

```
int main() {
    int N = 8;
    int left, right;

    left = 0;
    right = 7;

    int c[] = { 10, 5, 33, 16, 14, 56, 50, 7 }; //unsorted
    cout << "Before merge sort : " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << c[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "check if sorted before merge sort. " << endl;
    cout << isSorted(c, N) << endl;

    mergeSort(c, left, right);

    //values after sorting
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << c[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: When running in the debugger, on what line in the code show do the crash happen? Please indicate with a comment in the code. Then also please include the values of involved variables at that point as well. Also make sure the code you show actually *builds* (`new int[]` isn't valid C++ and should give you an error)

Comment: `new int[];` -- how big is this array that you think you just allocated, here? Hint: it's not as big as you think.

Comment: you didn't allocate enough space for array2 in merge function.

Comment: There should also be a check for size <= 1 at the start of merge() (in which case merge() should just return).

Comment: i changed the allocation of the new array to : int* array2 = new int[8].
The code now runs but produces wrong output i.e when i output the values after sorting in the main (after calling the mergeSort method" - the output is 5,7,-858993460,-858993460,-858993460,-858993460,8